# Setting up websockets with webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, websocket, webpack-dev-server

I can't get websockets to work with webpack-dev-server

the websocket server is running on port 4001 and webpack dev server is running on port 8080 ( I have enabled cors)

here is my react component

```
const App = () => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {

        if (socket) {
            socket.onerror = socket.onopen = socket.onclose = null

            socket.close()
        }

        const newSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4001')

        newSocket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('Connection to the websocket server established')
        }

        newSocket.onerror = (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }

        newSocket.onclose = () => {
            console.log('connection closed')
        }

        setSocket(newSocket)


        return () => {
            newSocket.close()
        }
    }, [])

}
```

I looked in the console and im getting this

WebSocketClient.js:18 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws' failed: Invalid frame header

First of all that is not even the url that i specified in the component.

So i added a proxy to the devServer config

```
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/ws': {
                target: 'http://localhost:4001',
                ws: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Then i checked the console again and it does this first

WebSocketClient.js:18 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws' failed: Invalid frame header

and then

index.js:23 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4001/' failed:

Here's a picture of the console.

[The console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QO9E.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the code of the websocket server?